Persistence criteria Fetch with treat to specific type
orderItems can be 2 types, StandardOrderItem and SpecificOrderItem
I wan't to get them fetching to avoid LazyInitialization exception.
It should be like this
orderService.findOrderByIdAndEntityGraph(productionOrderId,
  Map.of("orderItems",
    new JPAUtils.JoinNode(
      StandardOrderItem.class,
      Map.of("components", new JPAUtils.JoinNode(EMPTY_MAP))
      )));

Because SpecificOrderItem do ton contains "components"
which I want to fetch.
So unfortunatelly Join is lazy, fetch is eager but criteriaBuilder.treat() works only with joins, which causes errors on join of "components"
public static <T> T getBySpecificationWithGraph(
    EntityManager entityManager,
    Specification<T> specification,
    Map<String, JoinNode> joins,
    Class<T> clazz
  ) {
    CriteriaQuery<T> criteriaQuery = prepareCriteriaQuery(entityManager, specification, joins, clazz);
    return entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getSingleResult();
  }

  public static <T, V> Specification<T> fieldEquals(String fieldName, V value) {
    return (root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) ->
      criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get(fieldName), value);
  }

  private static <T> CriteriaQuery<T> prepareCriteriaQuery(
    EntityManager entityManager,
    Specification<T> specification,
    Map<String, JoinNode> joins,
    Class<T> clazz
  ) {
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<T> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(clazz);
    Root<T> ownerRoot = criteriaQuery.from(clazz);

    // Apply fetch logic with TREAT
    prepareFetch(joins, ownerRoot, null, criteriaBuilder);

    criteriaQuery.select(ownerRoot)
      .where(specification.toPredicate(ownerRoot, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder));
    return criteriaQuery;
  }

  private static <T> void prepareFetch(
    Map<String, JoinNode> joins,
    From<?, T> root,  // Use From to accommodate both Root and Join
    Fetch<?, ?> fetch,
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder
  ) {
    joins.forEach((key, value) -> {
      Fetch<?, ?> childFetch = null;
      Join<?, ?> childJoin = null;  // Declare childJoin for TREAT usage

      // Apply TREAT logic only on Fetches or Joins
      if (fetch == null) {
        if (value.getType() != null) {
          // First, attempt to treat it as a collection join
          try {
            // If the relationship is a collection (e.g., @OneToMany)
            SetJoin<Object, Object> setJoin = root.joinSet(key, JoinType.LEFT);
            childJoin = criteriaBuilder.treat(setJoin, value.getType());

            root.fetch(key, JoinType.LEFT);  // Ensure the association is fetched eagerly
          } catch (IllegalArgumentException | ClassCastException e) {
            // If it's not a collection, treat it as a singular join (e.g., @ManyToOne, @OneToOne)
            try {
              Join<Object, Object> join = root.join(key, JoinType.LEFT);
              childJoin = criteriaBuilder.treat(join, value.getType());

              root.fetch(key, JoinType.LEFT);  // Ensure the association is fetched eagerly
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException | ClassCastException ex) {
              throw new RuntimeException("Unable to apply TREAT to the join: " + key, ex);
            }
          }
        } else {
          // If no type is provided, just fetch the relationship
          childFetch = root.fetch(key, JoinType.LEFT);
        }
      } else {
        childFetch = fetch.fetch(key, JoinType.LEFT);
      }

      // Handle recursive joins and fetches for deeper relationships
      Objects.requireNonNull(value);
      Map<String, JoinNode> next = value.getJoins();

      if (!next.isEmpty()) {
        // Use childJoin for TREAT case or childFetch for normal cases
        if (childJoin != null) {
          prepareFetch(next, childJoin, null, criteriaBuilder);  // Continue joining with TREAT
        } else {
          prepareFetch(next, root, childFetch, criteriaBuilder);  // Continue fetching
        }
      }
    });
  }

  @Getter
  public static class JoinNode {
    private final Class<?> type;
    private final Map<String, JoinNode> joins;

    public JoinNode(Class<?> type, Map<String, JoinNode> joins) {
      this.type = type;
      this.joins = joins;
    }

    public JoinNode(Map<String, JoinNode> joins) {
      this.joins = joins;
      this.type = null;
    }
  }

Usage:
orderService.findOrderByIdAndEntityGraph(productionOrderId,
  Map.of("orderItems",
    new JPAUtils.JoinNode(
      StandardOrderItem.class,
      Map.of("components", new JPAUtils.JoinNode(EMPTY_MAP))
      )));

Explanation:
orderItems can be 2 types, StandardOrderItem and SpecificOrderItem
I wan't to get them fetching to aviod LazyInitialization exception.
It should be like this
orderService.findOrderByIdAndEntityGraph(productionOrderId,
  Map.of("orderItems",
    new JPAUtils.JoinNode(
      StandardOrderItem.class,
      Map.of("components", new JPAUtils.JoinNode(EMPTY_MAP))
      )));

Because SpecificOrderItem do ton contains "components"
which I want to fetch.
So unfortunatelly Join is lazy, fetch is eager but criteriaBuilder.treat() works only with joins, which causes errors on join of "components"

What is the goal exactly? Treat is used to also filter results - so if you could do what you want, you'd only get back StandardOrderItem instances if the 'components' collection contains reference instances of the subclass. JPA won't allow what you are attempting because the collection itself would be filtered - so your StandardOrderItem instance would have an incomplete view of the database data, ruining caching and management activities.

What you may want to try is specifying an entitygraph as a load graph. Your provider may join fetch these attributes, but they will be fetched before the entity returns.
